# How can I map a parameter of entity type with foreach tag of mybatis?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

There is an attribute of list type named 'carType' in an entity, the entity is like below:

```
public class Car{
     private List carType;
     private String carName;

     public void setCarType(List carType){
         this.carType = carType;
     }

     public List getCarType(){
         return carType;
     }

}
```

I assigned it a value before calling the DAO interface , just like :

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setCarType = [1,2,3];
List list = Dao.car(Car car);
```

Then I tried to map the parameter with foreach tag of mybatis:

```
  <select id='car'>
         select car_name, car_type from tb_car
         where car_type in
      <foreach item="item" collection="carType" separator="," open="(" close=")" index="">
         #{item}
      </foreach>
  </select>
```

Moreover, I hope the result is as follows:

```
select car_name, car_type from tb_car
where car_type in (1, 2, 3)
```

But the following error occurred after debugging：

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is 
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
invalid comparison: java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid comparison: 
java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String
```

I knew that I can fix it with parameter of Hashmap type, but could you tell me how to correct my code in this way ?

Comment: I would enable MyBatis' logging to see exactly what SQL ends up being rendered. If, for example, you used Log4j and the mapper namespace is "com.app1.mycarmapper" you should enable the logger "com.app1.mycarmapper.car'. Set the level to `DEBUG` or `TRACE`. That's the only way to find out for sure what is going on.

Comment: Also, make sure the generic list has a subtype. Instead of just `List` maybe you should use `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Good advice, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is parameter a List type? try `<select id='car' parameterType="java.util.List">`
Or `Car` type? try `<select id='car' parameterType="your.class.package.Car">`

Comment: The second one. Thanks , I'll try later